# how to reach grub menu in Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

Since I've forgot my password, I'm trying to reach grub menu in Ubuntu (2004.4.4.0 in Windows 11).

I've tried shift, Esc (while Booting / after ) and it didn't worked.

tried by, sudo grub-install /dev/sda , but it demand password, which I don't have.

thanks

Comment: Hello. I think that beside this wrong info here <2004.4.4.0 > Are you running WSL? You did not say that but what else could in Windows mean?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, when you cannot use root privileges because you lost your password here is what you can do:

- create a bootable medium which can mount your drive (e.g. Ubuntu Live USB)
- Boot from the stick and mount the root partition (/ -> to /mnt)
- chroot into the /mnt (sudo chroot /mnt)
- create a new password for the user you forgot the passwd (passwd username)
- enter new password

notice if you lost the disk encryption key/passphrase you are lost this is the purpose of encryption

to enter your GRUB2 Menu - I do not understand I see you are dual booting, depending on how you installed your OS (probably EFI if you use Windows alongside) you might want to get into the boot menu from your BIOS .. They key you have to press is depending on your manufacture.